# UJS: instruct 'change' event to fire only once when input field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a library that comes with Rails called Rails UJS: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

It has a custom event called 'change.rails' that fires when an input field changes and you tab away from the field. I am using the bootstrap-colorpicker library: https://itsjavi.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/

When you change the value of the select picker, it updates the input field and as you scroll through the color picker, millions of change events are fired and millions of ajax requests are sent to server.

I don't know how to circumvent that issue. I tried to add a timer to only send an ajax request after 3 seconds, but it still sends millions of ajax requests when changing the color:

```
    color_picker: function(){
        $color_picker.on('change.rails', $form_holder, function(event, xhr, settings) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $color_picker.trigger('change.rails');
            }, 3000)
            event.preventDefault();
        })
    }
```

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can store a reference to your timeout by setting it to a variable:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);
```

And then you can cancel that timeout by calling:

```
clearTimeout(timeout)
```

If you clear the timeout whenever the `'change.rails'` event occurs, your deferred ajax method won't fire until the timeout has had a chance to complete:

```
color_picker: function(){

    var timeout;

    $color_picker.on('change.rails', $form_holder, function(event, xhr, settings) {

        clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            $color_picker.trigger('change.rails');
        }, 3000)
        event.preventDefault();
    })
}
```